# Calculating the maximum likelihood estimator for the variance of iid normal RV's

Tags: maximum-likelihood, random-variable, estimators

I have that $X=(X_1,...,X_n)$ are iid RV's with $N$ $\sim (0, \theta)$ (Mean $0$ and variance $\theta \gt 0$.

I would like to show that the Maximum Likelihood estimator for $\theta$ is given by $$ \hat \theta(X)= \frac{1}{n} \sum^n_{i=1}X^2_i$$

So, i'm trying to prove it by definition: That the MLE is equal to argmax$L(\theta | x)$ for $\theta \in \Theta$ ($\Theta$ is the parameter space) and $L$ is the likelihood function.

So, here's how I do it:

[First im trying to compute the value for which the partial of the $log[L(\theta | x)]= \mathscr L(\theta |x)$ is equal to $0$]

$$\frac{\partial \mathscr L(\theta | x)}{\partial \theta}=\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta} \Bigl(\bigl(\frac{-n}{2} ln [2\pi \theta]\bigr) - \frac{1}{2 \theta} \sum^n_{i=1}x_i^2\Bigr)=0$$

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Biggl(-\frac{n}{2} \Bigl(ln[2 \pi] + ln[\theta] \Bigr)\Biggr) - \frac{1}{2 \theta} \sum ^n_{i=1}x^2_i=0$$
$$\frac{-n}{2\theta}+\frac{1}{2 \theta^2} \sum^n_{i=1}x^2_i=0$$

$$\sum^n_{i=1}x^2_i-\theta n=0$$

$$\theta = \frac{1}{n}\sum^n_{i=1}x^2_i$$

Ok, so far so good(?).

Now I need to show that it's a maximum by showing that the seocond derivative is negative. Here's where I get stuck:

$$\frac{\partial}{\partial \theta}\Biggl(\frac{-n}{2\theta}+\frac{1}{2 \theta^2} \sum^n_{i=1}x^2_i\Biggr)$$

$$\frac{n}{2 \theta^2} - \frac{1}{\theta^3} \sum^n_{i=1}x^2_i$$

But I don't see that this is negative? Am I doing this right?

Comment: You seem to suppose the derivative of  $1/\theta$ is $1/\theta^2,$ but the sign is incorrect.

Comment: @whuber So sorry, now I have edited the typos

Comment: Thank you.  Now all you have to do at the end is substitute $n\theta$ for $\sum x_i^2,$ because the second derivative is evaluated where $\theta$ equals the MLE.

Comment: @whuber thank you so much!