# What does checking the "behavior of the likelihood on the boundary of the parameter space" mean

Tags: estimation, maximum-likelihood, random-variable, estimators

[image]

What does the latter mean? If someone could explain. I already showed in [this question](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/447530/calculating-the-maximum-likelihood-estimator-for-the-variance-of-iid-normal-rvs?noredirect=1#comment832756_447530) that $\hat \theta(X)$ is the MLE.

Comment: The maximum of a differentiable function on an interval can occur at the boundary without the derivative being zero

Comment: @Henry Boundaries as in the endpoints of the function?

Comment: Yes, if it is a likelihood function of one parameter.  A little more complicated if there is more than one parameter

Comment: @Henry Well, there is one parameter $\theta$ where $X=(X_1,...,X_n) \sim N(0, \theta)$ (iid) for $\theta \gt 0$ . So I should compute the limit of the first derivative of the log-likelihood function with limits for $\theta$ - $0$ and also limit $\infty$?

Comment: Because in the referenced question the parameter space is $\{\theta\mid \theta\gt 0\},$ it is possible that the likelihood is maximized as $\theta\to 0^{+}$ or as $\theta\to\infty,$ conditions that will not be found by examining the zeros of the derivative.  (For this reason, your demonstration in the referenced question is incomplete.)

Comment: @whuber Ok, but do I compute those limits using the likelihood function or it's derivative?

Comment: This is Calculus, pure and simple: so when you're finding extremes of a differentiable function, you're taught to inspect the zeros of its derivative *and* the values of the function at the boundary.  That's all you have to do here.

Comment: @whuber Oh okay. I thought there was something more to this than just  this simple computing! Thanks

Comment: For completeness, I should add that generally you also have to check any values where the likelihood function is not differentiable.

Comment: @whuber Thank you! Appreciate it:)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It means that you will need to confirm that this indeed is a global maximum by showing that the second derivative of the likelihood function and that point is negative and to test the values of the likelihood at the boundaries $θ→0^+$ and $ θ→∞$ as whuber pointed out in his comment.